# Сборка динамической библиотеки в CLion (+ CMake)

Tags: cmake, сборка, clion

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю, что для получения DLL библиотеки в CLion достаточно вписать в CMake файл что-то вроде этого:

```
add_library(project_name SHARED src/library.cpp src/library.h)
```

Дело в том, что я именно это и вписал в CMakeLists.txt, но после сборки получаю библиотеку, которую не получается динамически подключить к другому проекту (для теста попробовал динамически подключить библиотеку libmariadb.dll - все работает, так что подключаю я правильно).

Также прилагаю код.

**1. library.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MY_LIB
#define MY_LIB __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MY_LIB __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" MY_LIB void testa(int a);
extern "C" MY_LIB bool testb();
```

**2. library.cpp**

```
#include "library.h"
#include <iostream>

void testa(int a) {
    std::cout << "This is 'A' function" << std::endl;
}

bool testb() {
    std::cout << "This is 'B' function" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

**3. CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project (MY_LIB)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1y -Wall")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/pdb)

#-------------------- Create a library -----------------------------------------
#Generate the shared library from the library sources
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
        SHARED
        src/library.cpp
        )


include(GenerateExportHeader)
generate_export_header(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

**4. Код программы, коей проверяю работу библиотеки**. Запускаю ее и в консоли указываю имя библиотеки (включая .dll). Сама библиотека (название.dll) лежит в папке с этой программой (вместе с .exe файлом). Если закинуть любую другую dll библиотеку в эту же папку и в консоли ввести ее имя, то она успешно загружается (я не получаю сообщение "Library ... is not found"). Однако, если указать имя моей dll, то получаю сообщение об ошибке, что библиотека не загружена (... is not found).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef int (*function)(int a);

std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s) {
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}

int main() {
    string name;
    cout << "Enter the name of library: ";
    cin >> name;

    wstring stemp = s2ws(name);
    LPCWSTR result = stemp.c_str();

    HMODULE hm = LoadLibrary(result);

    if (hm == NULL) {
        cout << "Library " << name << " is not found!" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else {
        cout << "Library " << name << " is loaded" << endl;
        function testa= (function)GetProcAddress(hm, "testa");

        testa(321);
    }

    FreeLibrary(hm);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: А `MY_LIB` у вас волшебным образом дефайнится? Вы https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html использовали?

Comment: @arrowd, Простите, снова я. Пришлось несколько помучиться, чтобы сообразить, как это подключить, но я смог. Но, к сожалению, лишь сейчас возник вопрос: а есть ли в этом вообще необходимость? Мне необходим лишь экспорт. То есть вполне достаточно было использовать вместо этих макросов всего лишь один:

#define MY_LIB __declspec(dllexport)

Именно это я и попробовал сделать. Однако, проблема осталось той же: я получил DLL файл, который не удается подключить к другому проекту динамически.

Comment: @arrowd, простите,  пожалуйста, я правильно понял, что мне необходимо было сделать следующее?

generate_export_header(${PROJECT_NAME} EXPORT_MACRO_NAME MY_LIB)

Comment: Просто `generate_export_header(project_name)` должно быть достаточно. Причем, тут `project_name` - это имя библиотеки (первый аргумент в `add_library`).

Comment: Если этого должно быть достаточно, то, к сожалению, проблема не разрешилась...

Comment: Нужно больше информации - текст ошибки, код CMake, код хедера.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, обновил информацию вверху вопроса. Еще, возможно, не лишним было бы сказать, что в проверке ``#ifdef MY_LIB`` пробовал вместо ``MY_LIB`` использовать ``MY_LIB_EXPORTS`` (заметил, что IDE этот макрос считает уже объявленным, поэтому из интереса проверил - результат все тот же).

Comment: Судя по вашему коду, вы вообще не используете сгенерированный симейком хедер с экспортами.

Comment: Да и раз вы используете динамическое связывание через `LoadLibrary`, вам вообще не нужен этот экспортный хедер. Просто собирайте библиотеку с аннотациями `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Comment: Я бы с радостью, только вот даже использование просто ``__declspec(dllexport)`` не связывает мою библиотеку с приложением. То есть, грубо говоря, вместо конструкции макросов оставил один макрос: ``#define MY_LIB __declspec(dllexport)``

Comment: (не знаю, как тут можно напомнить о себе, вдруг кто-нибудь все-таки знает, хах)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Препроцессорный дефайн необходим, т.к. когда вы компиляете приложение, использующее DLL, ее функции должны быть аннотированы `__declspec(dllimport)`, а когда компиляете саму DLL - `__declspec(dllexport)`. Если вы написали экспорт и там, и там, то библиотека нормально скомпилится, а с приложением будут проблемы.